# How to store .proto files

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, artifactory, proto, protobuf-java

Currently I store each protobuf contract files in a separate project dedicated to a concrete microservice.

So I have protobuf-my-microservice.jar for every microservice with compiled protobuf files inside. Then I upload these jars to artifactory and microservices are getting them at a build stage.

Would it be a good approach if I'd **store all contracts for all services in 1 artifact** ? (smth like a 1 library for all services)

I'll separate .proto files inside each microservice folder.
E.g.

```
/common
     /first-service/
          FirstService.proto
     /second-service/
          SecondService.proto
```

Not sure if I can do it cause it seems that I'm violating the single responsibility principle here.
Maybe there are any other problems I can face with using this approach?

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion that is quite popular, I think, is to create two separate projects.

First will contains `.proto` files only with messages (types), common for all services and maybe dedicated to one or more services. I suggest to organize them according to domains they belong to. Each `.proto` file represent some domain and messages relatedto it. You can import one `.proto` inside another one and reuse some common types with `import` ([docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#other)).

Second project will contains only `.proto` files with service definitions. Each service with its own `.proto`. This project will also depends on/use the first one.

One thing to clarify is that request/response messages should be declared in service's `.proto` files, so in the second project, not in the first one. While types used in those messages should be from first project.

To provide some example if we have a RPC providing some user data then `GetUserData` rpc, `GetUserDataRequest` and `GetUserDataResponse` messages should go into `user_data_service.proto` (as part of service's project). But if we assume that `GetUserDataResponse` returns something like `UserData`, then `UserData` message should goes into `user.proto` from the first project (types project), with all other user related messages.

Feel free to use this proposition, but of course there is nothing like "one single rule" to follow. That one just seems to be working quite well.